# iTunes Connect has published the wrong version to the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We've just released a new version of our app to fix all the issues that were created by iOS9. The new version went through review and was marked as ready for Sale.

iTunes Connect Lists the version as ready : "1.1.2 Ready for Sales"
The App Store lists the app with the new update : "What's New in Version 1.1.2"

But when we install the app (and when we uninstall it and reinstall it) we keep getting the old version : 1.1.1

I've not seen this particular bug in iTunes Connect before. Has something changed? Is there a new step we need to take to get it to install the new version?

Answer (score 0):

After it goes into the "Ready for sale" state, the new version must propagate through the cloud before the users start seeing it in the App Store.

Usually, this occurs within minutes, but sometimes it's hours.

It's generally a good idea to wait for it to update in the App Store before making any announcements to your end users about a new version being available.